# how to delete a particular file in Jenkins workspace via Jenkins groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have a Jenkins pipeline, which triggers a Jenkins groovy script via SCM, this script will create a file(if the file is not present) and write else it will update the file and doing some stuffs, this file need to be deleted.

below is the code of creating, writing and updating the file.

```
node(node_label){
     if (fileExists ( file_path+'/'+file_name ) ){
          def readContent = readFile file_path+'/'+file_name
          writeFile file: file_path+'/'+file_name, text: readContent+'\r\n'+data
     }else{
          writeFile file: file_path+'/'+file_name, text:data
     }
 }
```

after doing some stuffs, i need to delete this file,
i tried deleting this as below, but its not working.

```
def Delfile = new File(path+'/'+file_name)
Delfile.delete()
```

Comment: Hi, check my answer, I am using the same, but only for all jobs which are being loaded, so it should works. So, what is not working in your case? 
You should to be able to print `Delfile` (due naming convention, camel-case, should be delFile btw.., its a groovy, "based" on java). so question is what are the values of `path` and `file_name` ,.. Did you getting any error, or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

I have following for manual workspace cleanup, so as you mentioned it should work as well, check bellow.

I am assuming then you are probably not correctly getting file path

```
//load jobs
def jobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class)

//iterate over
for(job in jobs) {

//seems like they dont have workspace
  if(job instanceof hudson.model.ExternalJob){
    continue
  }


     String workspace = null

     //pipelines dont have workspace
     if(job instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob){
       println ("workflow job, not cleaning")   
       continue
     }

     try{
       workspace = job.workspace
     }catch(Exception e){
         //already clean eg.
       println ("no workspace, not cleaning")   
       workspace = null
     }

     if(workspace != null){
       //creation of the workspace and modules folder
       //again not sure, but sometimes was failing due boolean ..
       if(workspace instanceof java.lang.Boolean){
        println "cant cleanup"
        continue
       }

       File folder = new File(workspace) 

       //Check if the Workspace folder really exists
       if(folder!=null && folder.exists()){ 
         //workspace cleanup

         //get files
         File[] files = null
         try{
          files=new File(workspace).listFiles().sort(){
             //println it.name  

             if(!it.isFile()){
               it.deleteDir()
             }else{
               it.delete()
             }
           }
         }catch(Exception e){
            println "cant clean: " + workspace          
         } 

       }else{
        println "workspace is not existing, not cleaning"
       }  
   }
}
```

So, the core of the cleanup is:

```
  //get files
         File[] files = null
         try{
          files=new File(workspace).listFiles().sort(){
             //println it.name  

             if(!it.isFile()){
               it.deleteDir()
             }else{
               it.delete()
             }
           }
         }catch(Exception e){
            println "cant clean: " + workspace          
         }
```